# How to minimize SSE with given slope of 1?

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, excel

With given data, I need a line of slope 1 with minimized SSE. Anyone know how I could do this in R or Excel or another program?  If you could tell me how to do it mathematically that might help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The implied model for your data $(x_i, y_i)$ is to suppose each $y_i$ is an independent realization of a random variable $Y_i$ for which $\mathbb{E}(Y_i) = \alpha + x_i$.  It is usually assumed all the $Y_i$ have the same (unknown) finite variance.  The objective is to find $\alpha$ by means of least squares.

Recall that the least squares fit of a constant to *any* set of numbers is just their mean. Therefore the least squares estimate $\hat\alpha$ is the mean of the $y_i-x_i,$ equal to the difference of means $\bar y - \bar x$.  Coding this in `R`, `Excel`, or any other computing language is utterly simple.  Moreover, the usual formulas for the standard error of the mean continue to apply to $\hat\alpha,$ making it straightforward to test hypotheses about $\alpha,$ to supply confidence intervals for it, and so on.